# Preventing user to gain access after logout js

Tags: javascript, logout

I have made an html/css/javascript based webside. I created a logout page, where the user gets redirected to the login.html using

```
window.location = "login.html";
```

But ofcourse the user can gain back access to the site with simply using the "back-button" of the browser. Is there a way how i can prevent this?

Comment: On Server side you may use meta tag [expires](http://www.metatags.info/meta_name_expires), so that when user clicks on back button, browser will try to fetch from server again, which is not accessible due to session expiry. Also see [history API](http://mdn.io/history)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ensure user is redirected using JS. 
Because no matter how hard you try, user can just turn-off JS completely and open any page he wants.

I believe such checks have to be done using some basic server-side logic. After that you may add more client-side checks.

Comment: Consider marking question as closed if, well, question is answered, or ask more specific questions so SO community could help you find suitable answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess security is not a concern when are doing all this front-end.

u could use a cookie or localstorage to store the user authentication.

```
if($.cookie("username.isAuthenticated") == false)
    window.location = "login.html";
```